# Error in Creation of Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `go`()     
LANGUAGE SQL    
NOT DETERMINISTIC   
CONTAINS SQL    
SQL SECURITY DEFINER    
COMMENT '' 
BEGIN   DECLARE d_z CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '35241';     
SELECT COUNT(*)as @a from _time    
IF  @a>0 THEN           
SIGNAL d_z SET MESSAGE_TEXT='errrrrrrrrrrrr';   
END IF;  
END;
```

error:SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@a from _time
   IF  @a>0 THEN SIGNAL d_z SET MESSAGE_TEXT='errrrrrrrrrr' at line 9

Comment: Do you have a `DELIMITER` statement before this, so `;` won't be processed immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate error is caused by the malformed `SELECT` statement. You have to a proper [`SELECT INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) syntax

Change

```
SELECT COUNT(*)as @a from _time
```

to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @a FROM _time
                ^^^^
```

Now there are several other issues with your code:

1. There is no need to use a user(session) variable, you could've used local variable instead
2. You **don't want** to get total number of all rows just to tell whether you have rows or not in your table. If you do you'll pay performance penalty (if of course you're not using MyISAM). You can leverage `NOT EXISTS()` for that or `LIMIT 1` clause.

That being said a streamlined version of your procedure might look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `go`()     
BEGIN
  DECLARE d_z CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '35241';     
  IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM _time) THEN           
    SIGNAL d_z SET MESSAGE_TEXT='errrrrrrrrrrrr';   
  END IF;  
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51ae8/1)** demo

Let's give it a try

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE _time (`id` int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `go`()     
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE d_z CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '35241';     
    ->   IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM _time) THEN           
    ->     SIGNAL d_z SET MESSAGE_TEXT='errrrrrrrrrrrr';   
    ->   END IF;  
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> CALL go();
ERROR 1644 (35241): errrrrrrrrrrrr
```

Comment: but now error is:  
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd_z SET MESSAGE_TEXT='errrrrrrrrrrrr';   
  END IF;  
END' at line 5

Comment: Did you change `DELIMITER` as shown in the answer? Did you take a look at working sqlfiddle example provided?

Comment: It must be a problem with HeidiSQL. Just open mysql command line interface with `mysql -u<username> -p dbname` and then paste the provided code and execute it by hitting the enter.

Comment: Did it help after all?

Comment: Out of curiosity I just tested it with HeidiSQL 8.1 and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the select statement "@a" is alias name which cant be used further queries.

You can use peterm query "into" instead of as

Hope this helps

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You has some syntax issues. Following works for me:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `go`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE d_z CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '35241';
select count(*) INTO @a from _time;
IF  @a>0 THEN
SIGNAL d_z SET MESSAGE_TEXT='errrrrrrrrrrrr';
END IF;
END
//
```

Important is to:

1. Use into @variable syntax for selecting a value into a var
2. Use DELIMITER for termination of multiline procedure body

Comment: now error is:
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd_z SET MESSAGE_TEXT='errrrrrrrrrrrr';
END IF;
END' at line 11

Comment: Just use copy/paste to save the full content as shown. I have tested it with `MySQL 5.5.25` and it runs without any errors.